# ¿Cómo obtener la correlación entre las variables de objeto de un marco de datos?

Tags: python, python-3.x, estadística, categorical

Tengo un marco de datos con 49 columnas. La mayoría de ellas son de objeto tipo d. Intenté trazar el mapa de calor de la correlación de Pearson y ver la correlación de las variables independientes, pero parece que sólo se tienen en cuenta las variables numéricas.

En efecto, cuando intento

```
#Using Pearson Correlation
cor = df1.corr()

mask = np.zeros_like(cor, dtype=np.bool)
mask[np.triu_indices_from(mask)] = True
plt.figure(figsize=(12,10))
sns.heatmap(cor,
            vmin=-1,
            cmap='coolwarm',
            annot=False,
            mask = mask);
```

obtengo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esto es un extracto de mi base de datos:

```
>>> df1.head(3)
    Sexe    date_naissance  Groupe_dage     ville   Statut_marital  Niveau_de_scolarite     Situation_professionnelle   Autre_situation_professionnelle     Revenu_mensuel  Si_connexion_internet   Canal_acces_info    Autre_canal_acces_info  Si_situtation_ville_degradee    Si_intention_emigration     Besoin_Sante    Besoin_Education    Besoin_Conditions_de_vie    Besoin_Lutte_contre_criminalite     Besoin_Emploi   Besoin_Lutte_contre_corruption  Besoin_Eau_potable  Besoin_Infrastructures  Besoin_Culture_art  Besoin_Amelioration_services_publics    Besoin_Acces_logement   Besoin_Autres_besoins   Non_declaration_besoins     Autres_besoins  Si_connait_president_commune    Si_connait_parlementaires   Si_inscrit_LE   Si_vote_2016    Intention_vote_2021     Consentement    Langue_du_questionnaire     region  id_reg  status  nbr_app     adherent
0   Une femme   1964-04-15  Entre 45 et 54 ans  Al Hoceima  MariÃ© et je n'ai pas encore d'enfants Ã  charge    1er cycle universitaire / Licence   Je suis independent     NaN     5,000-7,499 DHS     Oui     Internet    NaN     Je suis d'accord    Je ne suis pas d'accord     True    False   True    False   True    False   False   False   False   False   False   False   False   NaN     Oui     Oui     Oui     Oui     Je sais dÃ©jÃ  pour qui je vais voter en 2021   J'accepter d'Ãªtre recontactÃ©  Arabe   Tanger-Tetouan-Al Hoceima   1.0     QualifiÃ©   3.0     True
1   Une femme   NaN     Entre 18 et 24 ans  TÃ©touan    CÃ©libataire    1er cycle universitaire / Licence   Je suis journalier, je travaille de temps Ã  a...   NaN     1-2,499 DHS     Non     Internet    NaN     Je suis d'accord    Je suis d'accord    True    True    False   False   True    False   False   False   False   False   False   False   False   NaN     Oui     Non     Non     NaN     Je ne voterai pas en 2021   Non     Arabe   Tanger-Tetouan-Al Hoceima   1.0     NaN     NaN     NaN
2   Un homme    NaN     Entre 25 et 34 ans  Khenifra    MariÃ© et j'ai des enfants Ã  charge    Niveau lycÃ©e   Je suis journalier, je travaille de temps Ã  a...   NaN     Je prÃ©fÃ©re ne pas rÃ©pondre   Non     TÃ©lÃ©vision    NaN     Je suis d'accord    Je suis d'accord    True    False   True    False   True    False   False   False   False   False   False   False   False   NaN     Oui     Non     Non     NaN     Je vais voter en 2021 mais je ne sais toujours...   J'accepter d'Ãªtre recontactÃ©  Arabe   Beni Mellal-Khenifra    5.0     Na veut pas rÃ©pondre   2.0     NaN
```

## El mio intento

Siguiendo [esta guía sobre la codificación categórica](https://pbpython.com/categorical-encoding.html) intenté lo siguiente:

```
# for each column where dtype is object
for column in df1.columns:
    if df1[column].dtypes == np.object:
        df1[column] = df1[column].cat.codes
```

Sin embargo, obtuve la siguiente salida:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-187-5f3d03cb1581> in <module>
      2 for column in df1.columns:
      3     if df1[column].dtypes == np.object:
----> 4         df1[column] = df1[column].cat.codes

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py in __getattr__(self, name)
   5268             or name in self._accessors
   5269         ):
-> 5270             return object.__getattribute__(self, name)
   5271         else:
   5272             if self._info_axis._can_hold_identifiers_and_holds_name(name):

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\accessor.py in __get__(self, obj, cls)
    185             # we're accessing the attribute of the class, i.e., Dataset.geo
    186             return self._accessor
--> 187         accessor_obj = self._accessor(obj)
    188         # Replace the property with the accessor object. Inspired by:
    189         # http://www.pydanny.com/cached-property.html

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\arrays\categorical.py in __init__(self, data)
   2510 
   2511     def __init__(self, data):
-> 2512         self._validate(data)
   2513         self._parent = data.values
   2514         self._index = data.index

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\arrays\categorical.py in _validate(data)
   2519     def _validate(data):
   2520         if not is_categorical_dtype(data.dtype):
-> 2521             raise AttributeError("Can only use .cat accessor with a 'category' dtype")
   2522 
   2523     def _delegate_property_get(self, name):

AttributeError: Can only use .cat accessor with a 'category' dtype
```